# Objects are not valid as a React child: Found object with keys {mytext. mydis}

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, FlatList, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'



let todos = [];
const MainScreen = () => {

    const [text, setText] = useState('')
    const [dis, setDis] = useState('')
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState({})


    //Use Effect Call Get Data

    useEffect(() => {
        getTask()
    }, [])


    // Get Data

    const getTask = async () => {

        try {


            const todoss = await AsyncStorage.getItem('todo');
            console.log(JSON.parse(todoss))
            // let value = JSON.parse(result)

            if (todoss !== null) {
                setTodo(JSON.parse(todoss));
            }


        }

        catch (e) {
            alert('Get Data ' )
        }

    }


    // Delete Task


    const clerText = async (index) => {
        const tempdata = todo;
        const selectedData = tempdata.filter((item, ind) => {
            return ind != index;
        });
        setTodo(selectedData)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(selectedData));
    };


    // Set Data 

    const saveTask = async () => {



        try {


          

            let temptodo = [];
            todos = [];
            let x = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('todo'));
            temptodo = x;

            temptodo.map(item => {
                todos.push(item);
            });

            todos.push({ text: text, dis: dis });
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todos));


          

            // getTask()


        }

        catch (e) {
            alert('Save Task ' + e)
        }

    }


    return (
        <View>
        <Text>Name</Text>
        <TextInput
            value={text}
            onChangeText={setText}
            style={{ borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 2, margin: 15, padding: 5 }}
            placeholder='Enter Task'
        />

        <TextInput
            value={dis}
            onChangeText={setDis}
            style={{ borderColor: '#000', borderWidth: 2, margin: 15, padding: 5 }}
            placeholder='Enter Task'
        />

        <Button
            title='Save Task'
            onPress={saveTask}
        />
        {/* {todo.map((val)=> <Text>{val}</Text>)} */}

        <Button
            title='Delete Task'
           
        />
        <FlatList data={todo}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                <View
                    style={styles.taskView}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.taskText}
                    >
                        {item.text}
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                        style={styles.taskDis}
                    >
                        {item.dis}
                    </Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={styles.taskBtn}
                        onPress={() => clerText(index)}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={styles.taskBtnText}
                        >
                            ❌
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )}
        />

        {/* <Text>{text}</Text>
  <Text>{todo}</Text> */}
    </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    taskView: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        margin: 30,
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
    },
    taskText: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'left',
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        marginVertical: 5,
        marginLeft: 15,
    },
    taskDis: {
        textTransform: 'capitalize',
        color: '#050505',


    },
    taskBtn: {
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
        marginVertical: 5
    },
    taskBtnText: {

    }
})
export default MainScreen
```

[image]

unknowing error ! please help me out

Comment: Did you get this error while these are not `{/* <Text>{text}</Text>
  <Text>{todo}</Text> */}` commented? If so it makes sense but other than this I do not think there is any error in your code.

Comment: you are right i checked 100 times my code i dont find and sort of error but i got this error again and again mytext and mydis objects not exist on my code !

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 const [todo, setTodo] = useState({})
```

To:

```
 const [todo, setTodo] = useState([])
```

Comment: not resolve same error again

Comment: Describe when the error occur.